# port.write in CodePage 437

Tags: c#, codepages

I am still learning c#, only been at it a few months...

I have a loop the prints in codepage(437) to a Epson & Bixolon thermal printer:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
  for (int n = 0; n < 42; n++)
  {
    var asciiBytes = new byte[] { 0x00DB };
    var asciiEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(437);
    port.Write(asciiBytes, 0, asciiBytes.Length);
  }
}
```

I am trying to simplify that by storing the ANSI character (it's > than the 0-127 normal range) as a var and print the var 3 times.

```
var F = "████████████████████████████████████████████████";
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    port.write(F);
}
```

But the printer prints Question marks instead. "?".

I need the F variable to print in CodePage(437).
My serial port, is just called 'port', as seen above.
I was the one that posted a similar question "Sending codepage(437) printer, some time ago. 
I'm just trying to streamline the printing process. The Bixolon printer handles it quickly, but the Epson slows to a crawl, it does print it, just slowly.
Thank you.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: var F = "████████████████████████████████████████████████";
                port.Encoding.CodePage.Equals(437);
                port.Write(F);
Still results in printing ??????? on paper.

Comment: port.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(437);
                port.Write(F + F + F);

Comment: Working now, thanks